# Run-time Error 1004 while Adding Comments to Cells with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am getting a Excel VBA run-time error 1004 : Application-defined or object-defined error while adding a comment to range of Excel cells with VBA.

The text for the comment comes out of a userform:

```
    Description = TextBox1.Value
    StartTime = TextBox2.Value
    EndTime = TextBox3.Value


InputText = StartTime & " - " & EndTime & "  " & Description
MsgBox (InputText)
```

This part works great. Afterwards there is some code to format the cells.
In the end VBA should add a comment to each cell.

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Selection
    Cell.AddComment
        Cell.Comment.Visible = False
        Cell.Comment.Text Text:=InputText  **'// ERRORLINE//**
    Next Cell
```

I already tried changing some code, without any luck:

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Selection
    'Cell.Comment.Delete
    Set Comment = Cell.Comment
        Cell.Comment.Visible = False
        Cell.Comment.Text Text:=InputText

        Next Cell
```

What works without any problems is:

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Selection
    'Cell.Comment.Delete
    Set Comment = Cell.Comment
        Cell.Comment.Visible = False
        Cell.Comment.Text Text:="InputText"

        Next Cell
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

clear the comment before adding a new one:

```
For Each cell In Selection
    With cell
        .ClearComments
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Visible = False
        .Comment.Text Text:=InputText
    End With
Next cell
```